# How to define templated component in RenderFragment with its @context available

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a templated component (a tooltip) that has a parameter and passes that parameter in context to child content. That parameter is a wrapper for `ElementReference`. The purpose of this is to get back to the tooltip the child's reference, once it is set.
What I want to do is to store a particular instance of that tooltip component in a reusable `RenderFragment` in several places.
But I get the error `The name 'context' does not exists in the current context`.

---

***This is original question, but it proved to be oversimplified. Please go to second separation line, with sample more resembling my situation.***

Here is a sample (not that tooltip, but simplified code that has exactly the same problem).
Templated component `RenderFragTempl`:

```cs
@inherits ComponentBase

<span id="@(Ref)">    
    @IntChildContent(Ref)
</span>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<int> IntChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public int Ref { get; set; }
}
```

and the call in `Index.razor`:

```cs
@page "/"
@using BlazorServer.Pages.StackOverflow

<RenderFragTempl Ref="10">
    <IntChildContent>
        <p>@context</p>
    </IntChildContent>
</RenderFragTempl>
<br />
@test

@code {
    //compiler error CS0103: The name 'context' does not exist in the current context
    private readonly RenderFragment test = @<RenderFragTempl Ref="10001">
        <IntChildContent>
            <p>@context</p>
        </IntChildContent>
    </RenderFragTempl>;

}
```

---

**EDIT: 1**
I have a tooltip component that has a child content. Tooltip will be shown whenever the mouse hovers over that child content. But tooltip does not wrap the child content with anything. So if you check out the source, you will only see the child content without any indication of the tooltip. The moment mouse cursor hovers over the child content, the tooltip container is added to the bottom of the page and is position right over that child content. This is quite problematic to achieve in blazor because the tooltip needs to have the reference to the child content. But references are established after parameters are filled. So a special wrapper is used to achieve that and Tooltip is built as a templated component.

So the wrapper for `ElementReference` I use (curtesy of MatBlazor):

```cs
    public class TargetForwardRef
    {
        private ElementReference _current;
        public ElementReference Current
        {
            get => _current;
            set
            {
                Set(value);
                //this is just for debugging purpose
                Console.WriteLine($"Ref: {value.Id ?? "null"}"); 
            }
        }
        public void Set(ElementReference value) => _current = value;
    }
```

My simplified `Tooltip` as `RenderFragTempl` (just the important bits)

```cs
@inherits ComponentBase

<span>            
    @UnboundChildContent(RefBack)
</span>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<TargetForwardRef> UnboundChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public TargetForwardRef RefBack { get; set; } = new TargetForwardRef();

}
```

And my `index.razor`

```cs
@page "/"
@* 
//this is working, will printout to console `<span>` reference id, you will be 
//able to find it once you go to source; I added this here for reference 
*@
<RenderFragTempl>
    <UnboundChildContent>
        <span @ref="@context.Current">Span content</span>
    </UnboundChildContent>
</RenderFragTempl>
<br/>
@test

@code {
    //compiler error CS0103: The name 'context' does not exist in the current context
    private readonly RenderFragment test = 
    @<RenderFragTempl>
        <UnboundChildContent>
            <span @ref="@context.Current">Hover to show tooltip</span >
        </UnboundChildContent>
    </RenderFragTempl>;

}
```

To answer the question - why I am trying to use `RenderFragment` - imagine I have a collection of cards - let's say 150. The card component accepts as a parameter `IList<RenderFragment>` for rendering buttons on a card. I want to pass my icon with tooltip to that card. I need to have access to Tooltip's context.

I tried renaming context to something else, but I get the same error (except in the error there is new context name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why define a templated component and use it like that ?

However, here's code sample that demonstrates how to get the same required result without defining a templated component:

```
@test(12)

@code {
    
    private RenderFragment<int> test => (value) => (__builder) =>
    {
        <span id="@(value)">
            @value
        </span>
    };

}
```

But if you insist, here's the code that demonstrate how to render your component:

```
@test((10001, 15))

@code 
{
    private RenderFragment<(int, int)> test => (value) => (__builder) =>
    {
        <RenderFragTempl Ref="@value.Item1">
            <IntChildContent>
                <p>@value.Item2</p>
            </IntChildContent>
        </RenderFragTempl>;
   
    };

 }
```

### Update:

The following code describes how to render the templated component with the internal variable context. You can improve on it as you like.

Note: I did not read your update... I just do what you requested on the original question, but this time using context.

```
@test(121)

@code {
    
    private RenderFragment<int> test => (value) => (__builder) =>
        {
        __builder.OpenComponent<TemplatedComponent>(0);
        __builder.AddAttribute(1, "Ref", value);
        __builder.AddAttribute(2, "IntChildContent", 
            (RenderFragment<int>)((context) => (__builder2) =>
            {
                __builder2.OpenElement(3, "p");
                __builder2.AddContent(4, context);
                __builder2.CloseElement();
            }
            ));
            __builder.CloseComponent();

        };

}
```

Note that when you invoke the RenderFragment delegate you pass it a value which is assigned to the Ref parameter, and is passed in the form the the internal context variable

Comment: I had a feeling I oversimplified it. As I stated - I have a tooltip that needs reference of its child (it does not wrap child content with any element). So basically it is important to get the context of the tooltip's template to be used by child content. There is a scenario when whole page will be filled with components that will be using the same tooltip (with the same hint). I really need to access that context... I will alter my question - hopefully it will better reflect my needs.

Comment: Sorry, but the new alterations merit a new question. Please, accept my answer, and create a new question, and I'll try to help here...

Comment: The question is the same. I still am trying to use the context. The core of the question did not change, only the simplified (though more complex then original) example did. I really appreciate your answer, but it did not answer my direct question. You offered a workaround to my oversimplified example, but not an answer to my question about using the context. Again, I would like to emphasize, I really am thankful for your input.

Comment: See Update section in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I actually came up with the same solution myself yesterday. Even posted it here https://github.com/ant-design-blazor/ant-design-pro-blazor/pull/68 - I was really hoping to get less verbose solution, that maybe does not need the use of RenderTreeBuilder so directly. I will ask the same question in github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore, maybe there is something we do not know. If I am going to get the same answer (or similiar), I will mark your answer as accepted. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Undeleted my answer... Have the pleasure to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question in https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29671 and I got an answer. This is not exactly what I wanted, but that seems to be official:

```cs
    private readonly RenderFragment<TargetForwardRef> test => context => 
    @<RenderFragTempl>
        <UnboundChildContent>
            <span @ref="@context.Current">Hover to show tooltip</span >
        </UnboundChildContent>
    </RenderFragTempl>;
```

Comment: "I really need to access that context", "I still am trying to use the context": Your context is not the internal context produced by the rendering  engine, it is simply a parameter passed to the Razor template.